# Execution failed for task ':Project:processDebugResources

Tags: android

[image]This is my error:-

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/user/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How to resolve this problem I am trying it to resolve last two days..but didn't get it..Please anybody can help me.

Comment: What is your "buildToolsVersion" in build.gradle?

Comment: please send logcat output

Comment: Can u post your gradle file.

Comment: We have posted our logcat screen please help

Comment: In your log I can see that "Attribute `rippleColor` has already been defined".. So please correct it.. And check it again..

Answer (score 0):

It may happen when your application exceeds the 65k method limit.

To build apps with more than 65k methods you must add multi dex support.
Add these to your app gradle file.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14 // Multi Dex not supported below 14
    targetSdkVersion 23

    multiDexEnabled true // To Enable Multi Dex
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false /*Include these three statements to build app quickly (at least faster than     before :p) */
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"  // To avoid GC Limit Exception
    jumboMode = true  // To avoid GC Limit Exception
}

}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /* MultiDex - method count exceeds 65k */
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Now make an Application Singleton Class and Override `attachBaseContext()`

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Don't forget to declare it in your Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".AppController" <!-- Your Application Singleton Class Name -->
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
    ...
    </application>
```

Due to memory limitations in android studio you still might get GC Error.
Try cleaning you project and then building it again.

You're all set now!

Comment: In our project contains many modules library project, and every module projects contained manifest file and gradle so we have to change in every gradle of module projects ?

Comment: @JunaidQureshi no you just have to change the gradle of your application module.

Comment: @JunaidQureshi According to your log cat. It's probably is an error due to duplicate attribute `rippleColor`. It happens when there are more than one xml attributes declared with the same name.

Comment: @JunaidQureshi if you have recently added any module please check it's source code for the attribute `rippleColor`.